# Textures for Animating in 2D OpenGL (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I have been looking for an answer but haven't found anything specific about it.

I'd like to know what of these two examples is better related with speed and performance. Thanks in advance!

I am making a openGL ES 1.0 Android Game in 2D. For animating the characters I use different textures. I have two posibilities with the textures:

First one is to have each texture in an int Array and change which one is selected depending on the frame with:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[actual_id]);
```

On the other hand we can have a "Big" texture with all the images and just modify the Texture coordinates. In this case instead of:

```
private float textures[] = {
    // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
    0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
    0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
    1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
    1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
};
```

(Which would be the one in the first case) It would be:

```
private float textures[] = {
    // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
    0.0f, 0.5f,     // top left     (V2)
    0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
    0.5f, 0.5f,     // top right    (V4)
    0.5f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
};
```

(Using a 2x2 box) And those coordinates should move around the texture.

I would like to know which may be the fastest. Also, if there is a third best way I'd love to know about it.

Thanks for your time. If I have to detail the question please ask me.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. You may want to know that 'preference' questions like this are generally considered to be not appropriate (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)). Having said that, you may want to pick a single criteria that interests you most. I don't believe that one method is 'better' than another (one may be faster, another may use less memory), and this could easily change from one device to another. If you can pick one important criteria and rephrase your question to ask only that i.e. *which method uses less memory*, it may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'd like to know which one is the fastest more than the use of memory. I'm going to modify the question, thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no general answer to this question because it depends on some other things.

I assume you have a lot of other objects besides the characters to draw. Lets assume you have a game loop that looks something like this:

```
while (gameNotFinished) {
  changeToTerrainTexture()
  drawTerrain()
  changeToCharacterTexture()
  drawCharacter() // the character you want to draw
  changeToHouseTexture()
  drawHouse()
  ...
}
```

In this case you have to change to the character texture anyway. The first way would be the better solution because the smaller texture requires less texture memory.

But if your loop looks like this:

```
while (gameNotFinished) {
  changeToTerrainTexture()
  drawTerrain()
  changeToCharacterTexture()
  for (int i = 0; i < characters.size(); i++) {
    characters.get(i).draw()
  }
  ...
}
```

In this case you can profit from the second way because you can display multiple characters in different animation states without changing the texture.

I don't know if there is any real alternative with OpenGl ES 1.0. With ES 2.0 you would have the option to use one texture for multiple animation states (like your 2nd approach) and compute the texture coordinate offsets within the shader (so you don't need multiple texture coordinate arrays).

Comment: So, if we have several characters but each one has their own textures, first option would be nice? 

Thanks for your anwser!

Comment: Yes, if you need to switch the texture for each character you would not gain a real benefit from #2